# Send input from function to class

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, input

Python beginner here.
I am having hard time understanding how to get user input from function to use it in one of my class methods

```
class...
    def setFirstStageSpeed(self, s):
        s = # FIRST_STAGE_SPEED from main()
        self.Speed = s

...

def main():
    FIRST_STAGE_SPEED = 0
    while True:
        try:
            FIRST_STAGE_SPEED = int(input("Please set first stage speed"
                                           "for the spacecraft: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
            continue
        if FIRST_STAGE_SPEED < 0:
            print("Sorry, your response must not be negative.")
            continue
        else:
            break
...
```

So as shown above, I am trying to get the input value on FIRST_STAGE_SPEED to the setFirstStageSpeed() method.

Comment: You could _call_ `yourInstanceOfClass.setFirstStageSpeed(FIRST_STAGE_SPEED)`, as such. You'd need to create an instance of the class first, though you haven't actually told us what the name of the class is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.you should creaete a instance of SpaceCraft.that's OOP style.

```py
class SpaceCraft:
    def setFirstStageSpeed(self, s):
        self.Speed = s


def main():
    FIRST_STAGE_SPEED = 0
    while True:
        try:
            FIRST_STAGE_SPEED = int(input("Please set first stage speed"
                                           "for the spacecraft: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
            continue
        if FIRST_STAGE_SPEED < 0:
            print("Sorry, your response must not be negative.")
            continue
        else:
            break

    # make a instance of SpaceCraft.if you not familiar with OOP(Object-oriented programing).you should study about it
    spaceCraft = SpaceCraft()
    # then call the instance method.set the first stage speed
    spaceCraft.setFirstStageSpeed(FIRST_STAGE_SPEED)
```